Testrail Issue I am not able to send robot framework report to Testrail
I am trying to send reports to testrail but reports are not going i refer all the documentation of testrail
for sending reports
i have enabled API and added Add Field
 TestRail CLI v1.9.5
Copyright 2024 Gurock Software GmbH - www.gurock.com
Parser Results Execution Parameters
> Report file: D:\automation-frameworks-integration-main\samples\robotframework\robotframework-browser\sample_reports\junit-report.xml
> Config file: None
> TestRail instance: https://gmramp.testrail.io
> Project: RTOS Apps
> Run title: RF Automated Tests
> Update run: No
> Add to milestone: No
> Auto-create entities: True
Parsing JUnit report.
Processed 3 test cases in section Tests.
Checking project. Done. 

its getting stuck in Checking project. Done.  after that i was not going forward
i have enabled API and added Add Field
trcli -y -c "tricli-congif.yml" parse_robot -f "D:\automation-frameworks-integration-main\samples\robotframework\robotframework-browser\sample_reports\junit-report.xml"

its was working up to checking project. Done.  then stop working
